# How to create an arrow shape after an element with :after

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I created a hexagon with css which is working well. Now, I am attempting to create somewhat of an arrow to set under the hexagon. In my attempt, I used the pseudo element, `:after` to try to position the line after the hexagon. For some reason the line is appearing at the top of the hexagon.

This leads me to the next issue, outside of the placement. How would I create an arrow type line (see illustration below) with `:after`. Is it even possible?

Is there a better way to do this?

[image]

```css
#hexGrid {
    width: 60%;
 position: absolute;
 margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
 right: 5%;
 top: 35%;
}
#hexGrid li {
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    width: 27.85714285714286%;
    padding: 0 0 32.16760145166612% 0;
    -o-transform: rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
    transform: rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
    overflow: hidden;
    visibility: hidden;
}
#hexGrid li * {
    visibility: visible;
}
#hexGrid li .hexagon {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #2f2f2f;
    -o-transform: skewY(-30deg) rotate(60deg);
    -moz-transform: skewY(-30deg) rotate(60deg);
    -webkit-transform: skewY(-30deg) rotate(60deg);
    -ms-transform: skewY(-30deg) rotate(60deg);
    transform: skewY(-30deg) rotate(60deg);
    overflow: hidden;
}
.hexagon:after {
 content: '';
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 margin-top: 10px;
 width: 50%;
 height: 3px;
 background: #b82222;
}
```

```html
<ul id="hexGrid">
  <li>
    <div class="hexagon">
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Why are you preferring this solution above an svg?

Comment: @JoostS I wasn't aware an SVG was an option. I do not know how to create SVG shapes.

Comment: Inkscape is a good starting point. 'Images for web' equals 'SVG'. Only pixel data, like photo's should not be SVG.

Comment: @JoostS Does an image make sense though? Wouldn't a pure CSS solution be ideal?

Comment: You want to create an image, but you choose to create it with HTML (pseudo) elements and CSS border tricks. Not very logical. An actual image (SVG) is just as small and makes more sense in this case.

Comment: Nice work on the hexagon, but I think the `overflow: hidden;` on the li is going to cause some issues. Whether you make the arrow an svg or just a css shape, I would think you'll need to not nest it in the li.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you would change the size of hexagon:

```css
#container {
  margin: 50% auto 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 2px;
  border: 1px solid;
  transform: translate( 0, -50%)
}

#container>div {
  transform: scale(2) translate(50%, 50%); 
}

#chevron {
  margin-top: 40%;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  /* try to add more padding and see the difference*/
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  height: 5px;
  width: 100px;
}

#chevron:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  background: red;
  transform: skew(0deg, 28deg);
}

#chevron:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  background: red;
  transform: skew(0deg, -28deg);
}

#hexagon {
  width: 100px;
  height: 55px;
  background: #616161;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

#hexagon:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -25px;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 25px solid #616161;
}

#hexagon:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -25px;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  border-top: 25px solid #616161;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="hexagon"></div>
  <div id="chevron"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: because `scale` method, and that will make the text twice the size, and you are using `2em` text size so it should be huge

Answer (score 1):

SVG will be the best solution for this problem.. But still if you want it with CSS, you can create 3 Hexagons and overlap it at 10px gap.

Snippet below:

```css
#hexGrid {
    width: 60%;
 position: absolute;
 margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    right:5%;
 top: 35%;
}
#hexGrid li {
    list-style-type: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 27.85714285714286%;
    padding: 0 0 32.16760145166612% 0;
    -o-transform: rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
    transform: rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
    overflow: hidden;
    visibility: hidden;
}
#hexGrid li:nth-child(2){
  top:-10px;
}
#hexGrid li:nth-child(2) .hexagon{
    background: #fff;
}
#hexGrid li:nth-child(3){
  top:-20px;
}
#hexGrid li * {
    visibility: visible;
}
#hexGrid li .hexagon {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #2f2f2f;
    -o-transform: skewY(-30deg) rotate(60deg);
    -moz-transform: skewY(-30deg) rotate(60deg);
    -webkit-transform: skewY(-30deg) rotate(60deg);
    -ms-transform: skewY(-30deg) rotate(60deg);
    transform: skewY(-30deg) rotate(60deg);
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<ul id="hexGrid">
  <li>
    <div class="hexagon">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hexagon white">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hexagon arrow">
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Again, I would prefer SVG over this solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way of doing that

```css
#chevron {
   margin-top: 25px;
      position: relative;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 0; /* try to add more padding and see the difference*/
      margin-bottom: 6px;
      height: 5px; /* change this to make it bigger */
      width: 100px;
    }
    #chevron:before {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      height: 100%;
      width: 50%;
      background: red;
      transform: skew(0deg, 28deg);
    }
    #chevron:after {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      height: 100%;
      width: 50%;
      background: red;
      transform: skew(0deg, -28deg);
    }
  

    #hexagon {
      width: 100px;
      height: 55px;
      background: #616161;
      position: relative;
   margin-top: 50px;
    }
    #hexagon:before {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      top: -25px;
      left: 0;
      width: 0;
      height: 0;
      border-left: 50px solid transparent;
      border-right: 50px solid transparent;
      border-bottom: 25px solid #616161;
    }
    #hexagon:after {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      bottom: -25px;
      left: 0;
      width: 0;
      height: 0;
      border-left: 50px solid transparent;
      border-right: 50px solid transparent;
      border-top: 25px solid #616161;
    }
```

```html
<div id="hexagon"></div>
<div id="chevron"></div>
```

Comment: Is there anyway to make this scalable? For instance, I changed the hexagon width/height and now it looks nothing like a hexagon.

Comment: well, you can change the width and height for . `#hexagon` and then change the `:after` and `:before` borders. so if you made the width x3 of original size then do the same for the borders. or you can wrap it with a new container and change the scale and the width at 100% of the child, which is `#hexagon` in this case and make `#container { width:300px} /* or whatever you want */`